# Send keys to a twebbrowser?

Tags: delphi

How do I programatically send keys to a TWebBrowser to fill in data fields like Name and address?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to fake input you need to use the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.

However, that's going to require you to make sure that field in question has the input focus. I suspect you would be better off poking the data in through the DOM ([`IWebBrowser2.Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752116%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: +1. The DOM sounds right to me (although I have no experience of it).

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want just to fill in some data in some edit boxes.
If yes, this might be useful for you http://delphi.about.com/od/twebbrowser/a/submit_web_form_2.htm

Answer (score 1):

The most robust way would be to use the DOM as suggested previously. However if you end up going via the simulated input route, the Delphi `SendKeys` unit will make things much easier. 
Article and download available here: http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2004/a/bltip1104_3.htm