# Send Ctrl+Key to a 3rd Party Application

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe, keystroke

Im using a 3rd Party Application that exports a file. The application uses a hot key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) as a shortcut for this function.

How can I send this key combination from my Delphi XE application to the 3rd Party one?

Comment: Are you talking about WinAPI here? Relevant tag would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example which shows how to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to the foreground application using [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
var
  Inputs: array [0..3] of TInput;
begin
  // press
  Inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_CONTROL;
  Inputs[0].ki.dwFlags := 0;

  Inputs[1].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[1].ki.wVk := Ord('E');
  Inputs[1].ki.dwFlags := 0;

  // release
  Inputs[2].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[2].ki.wVk := Ord('E');
  Inputs[2].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

  Inputs[3].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[3].ki.wVk := VK_CONTROL;
  Inputs[3].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

  SendInput(Length(Inputs), Inputs[0], SizeOf(TInput));
end;
```

I also use a slightly modified version of SendKeys.pas from Steve Seymour. It had some problems with different keyboard layouts and is from 1999. Couldn't find it anywhere in the net.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. This solved my problem in a couple of seconds. ;)

Answer (score 3):

See question: [Send keys to a twebbrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968901/send-keys-to-a-twebbrowser)
There is an answer there (Matt Handel) that links to an article with an example of using the SendKeys unit, and obtaining the handle of the target window.