# How to send a "TAB" keystroke to another program?

Tags: delphi, keystroke

I'm trying to make a program that would process some bar code to make it compatible with online banking. The catch is that the app must work with an already opened Firefox window. To make it compatible the app must remove "." (dots) and paste it part by part (total of 5 parts) in the online banking window. How can I send a "tab" (like the key in keyboard) to the online banking window to move thru the 5 editboxes that exists for the pieces of bar code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8429253/62576

Comment: Hello Ken, thanks for the reply, now let me ask, are you watching me? =)

Comment: Nope. I watch questions in topics I'm interested in, of which Delphi is one. You've posted three separate questions tagged Delphi in the last hour or so. if you look at my profile, you'll see I'm quite active in the Delphi tags here.

Comment: great. so you can help me.

Comment: @FernandoSBS - You are attrackting attention for sure but you might find the pool of people willing to help getting dried up pretty soon. Getting this much downvotes on this many questions should be a sign to you to improve on asking questions by at least showing us the efforts you made trying to solve the questions you have for yourself. Note that that doesn't equate to just dump an entire project here but actually take the time to formulate a decent  question. To quote George: "It always amazes me that people expect me to spend my time answering questions they won't spend their time asking."

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers If you check my history I have always ask "better" questions. The problem here with Delphi is that I have poor knowledge. It's a fact that even to ask questions about something knowledge is imperative. I am also from Brazil, so my english is not that good. And also it would be better if I could ask all the questions in the same page, and not open a new question for every problem like it has to be done in StackOverflow. But you are absolutely right and I am sorry for the poor quality of the questions, and I thank all that helped, except Ken White who was only complaining.

Comment: @FernandoSBS - If you put in some effort *(as you do now)* you'll find you **can** learn a lot on SO, especially from people like Ken. Maybe he worded it more harsh than it meant to be or maybe you've misinterpreted the intention but from what I've read in the past from Ken, I'm pretty conffident no hard feelings were intended.

Comment: I've got banned because of the negative reviews of the questions. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Ok so I've tried to improve all the questions that I've asked yesterday about delphi. Hope it's more understandable now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
PostMessage(OtherProgramWindow.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);
PostMessage(OtherProgramWindow.Handle, WM_KEYUP, VK_TAB, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a component called "SendKeys" available on Torry's Delphi pages that will allow you to send keystrokes to another window very easily. It pushes the keystrokes into the Windows keyboard buffer using Windows' keybd_event function.

http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=sendkeys&Title=Yes

Answer (score 1):

So I've finally find the best solution for the problem.

First:

```
SetForegroundWindow(Appwin);
```

Makes it 100% sure that the "tab" command is send to the right window.

Second:

```
Keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, 0, 0);
```

Send a keyboard event "TAB" key to that window.